# Convert array of dates into month name

Tags: php

I have array of dates like this:-

```
Array
(
[0] => 2016-08-31
[1] => 2016-08-30
[2] => 2016-08-29
[3] => 2016-08-01
[4] => 2016-07-01
[5] => 2016-06-01
[6] => 2016-05-01
[7] => 2016-04-01
[8] => 2016-03-01
[9] => 2016-02-01
[10] => 2016-01-01
)
```

Need to convert into month name like January, February without repeating month name, and store into another array to use as an JSON Object.

I tried `date("F", strtotime($dates));` but returning December for 8, rather than august.

Comment: you need to convert one by one for all or at once you need it

Comment: at once and store it in another array

Comment: Provided and output bro. It will be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You  have to use foreach after that you can json encode the data.

```
<?php
$month_value=[];
foreach ($values as $key => $monthval) {
    $month_value[] = date('F',strtotime($monthval));
}
$months = array_unique($month_value);
$final_month = json_encode($months); // this output will be a json value
?>
```

Comment: Where `$values` is your array containing the dates.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly used array_unique with that

Comment: Have you obtained the required output bro. if so u feel , you can promote my answer.

Comment: yes got required output.. sorry new to stack, so confused with multiple answers :-)

Comment: No issues. if you feel all are good replies you can upvote all the answers to so that it will be useful for all. Or rather if you feel the best one you can apply green tick over to the answer.

Comment: But it is mandatory to award every developer since this is all the credits for him/her..

Answer (score 1):

You need to through dates and store the months in new array and apply [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
$dates = [
    '2016-08-31',
    '2016-08-30',
    '2016-08-29',
    '2016-08-01',
    '2016-07-01',
    '2016-06-01',
    '2016-05-01',
    '2016-04-01',
    '2016-03-01',
    '2016-02-01',
    '2016-01-01',
];

$months = [];
foreach($dates as $date) {
    $months[] = date('F', strtotime($date));
}

$months = array_unique($months);
var_dump($months);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store unique months in the array variable **$months_list**.

> **Approach 1** : We are looping through each date, calculating the month and appending the month only if it's not found in the **$months_list** array.

Try this:

```
$months_list = [];

foreach($dates as $date) {
    $month = date('F', strtotime($date));
    if (!in_array($month, $months_list)) {
        $months_list[] = $month;
    }
}
```

> **Approach 2**: Applies the callback function using [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and converts each dates to month names. Then, we can apply[array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function to pick unique month names.

```
$months_list = array_map(function($date){
    return date('F', strtotime($date));
}, $dates);

$months_list = array_unique($months_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method: jdmonthname(...) you can use.
Here's a code:

```
  $dates = Array(
    '2016-08-31',
    '2016-08-30',
    '2016-08-29',
    '2016-08-01',
    '2016-07-01',
    '2016-06-01',
    '2016-05-01',
    '2016-04-01',
    '2016-03-01',
    '2016-02-01',
    '2016-01-01'
  );

  foreach ($dates as $value) {
    $date = explode('-', $value);
    $year = intval($date[0]);
    $month = intval($date[1]);
    $day = intval($date[2]);
    $jd = gregoriantojd($month, $day, $year);
    echo jdmonthname($jd, 1) . '<br />';
  }
```